# Как сделать чтобы Num_2 не мог быть больше Num_1?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random randNum = new Random();

            double num;
            Console.WriteLine("Введи цифру минимальную:");
            var num_2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введи максимальную цифру:");
            var num_1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (num_2 > num_1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка, вы ввели неправильные символы!");
            }
            else
            {
            }
            num = randNum.Next(+num_2, +num_1);
            Console.WriteLine("Твое рандом число:" + num);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var num_2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` попросите юзера об этом, юзер же его вводит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать что-то подобное:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random randNum = new Random();

        double num;
        Console.WriteLine("Введи цифру минимальную:");
        var num_2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введи максимальную цифру:");
        var num_1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while(num_2 > num_1){
            Console.WriteLine("Введи цифру минимальную:");
            num_2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        num = randNum.Next(+num_2, +num_1);
        Console.WriteLine("Твое рандом число:" + num);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: интересно что будет, если вести минимальное значение как `2147483647` :)

Comment: кстати, вы внутри цикла создаете новую переменную

Comment: пардон, копипаст

Comment: Все, я решил эту проблему, только теперь образовалась новая! Когда я ввожу неправильно мне всю консоль заспамивает!

Comment: while (num_2 > num_1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка, вы пытаетесь ввести неправильные символы!");
    }

Comment: `num = randNum.Next(+num_2, +num_1);` для чего тут плюсы?

Comment: Не знаю) Я только начал учить C#

Comment: @huba1337 у вас проблемы с копированием ответа к себе в редактор. Попробуйте ещё раз

Comment: Я все сделал, просто как сделать чтобы ошибка высвечивалась только 1 раз? А не заспамила консоль и нагружала процессор до 30%

Comment: @huba1337 уберите цикл, будет 1 раз

Comment: Как? Я не совсем понимаю? <pre>while (num_2 > num_1) { Console.WriteLine("Ошибка, вы пытаетесь ввести неправильные символы!"); } </pre> где тут цикл?

Comment: @huba1337 вы знаете, что делает оператор `while`?

Comment: Нет, мне его написали

Comment: @huba1337 тогда вам надо ознакомиться с [основами языка программирования](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/) прежде чем что то на нем писать.

Comment: Если я ставлю break; то окно просто закрывается